# Is there any library that supports zooming in/out an angular div or text or image with angular 10+

Tags: css, angular, angular-material, angular11

Is there any library that supports zooming in/out a div or angled text or image, but zooming starts from the center instead of from the left as depicted in the image below.
i tried using css with transform: scale() property but when zooming in from the center it loses 1 of the left part, only works when zooming in from the left

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4O3WO.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: use [transform-origin:center](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-origin)